# Function defined implicity

Tags: real-analysis

I have $ f(x,y)=x^2-y^2+y^4$.Does it define a  function y=h(x) or x=g(y) in around zero? Can I use Dini's teo?

Comment: Do you want $f(x,y)=0$? Note that then $f(\pm x, \pm y)=0$ because you have both to even powers.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the equation $y^4-y^2+x^2=0$ you will get, for example,  $y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}$  for $|x| \le 1/2$.

This function satisfies $y(0)=0.$

Comment: y(x) have to be $C^1 $ around zero?

Comment: How do you distinguish between the values for the square root, which are not distinguished in the original equation?